# Russian text is not working in Android game when ported from iOS using Apportable SDK

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

I have successfully ported our game to **Android from iOS using Apportable starter SDK.**

I have come across a issue in which the device is decoding Russian text of the game , i have included screen shots and where i have given such Russian texts in xcode.As you see from the  i have typed the word **"Test"** in English which is displayed properly and whereas the Russian text is displayed in some form of code.

`NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\n  Test Разъезжая по сказочным землям и устраивая веселые дискотеки, я добрался до Пушляндии. Я много слышал о веселых и дружных жителях этой страны - Пушистиках. Узнав о моем появлении, они шумной толпой прибежали на мою вечеринку..."];`

Stack overflow is not allowing me to add screenshots so i am adding links.The first screenshot shows the way i want the text to display in android adb second screenshot shows the current way its displayed.

I will provide more detailed description or code if required.

**Screenshot iOS:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcWRV.jpg
[image]
**Screenshot Android:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHcvk.jpg
[image]

Comment: I think is because you don't use localization in app

Comment: @sage444 We did not use Localization in the iOS game. It is specifically made with russian text and images. it is the only language available in the game.

Comment: @sage444 I will implement localization in app today, i will report the status to you.

Comment: I have solved it by Using Localization in my App. Thank you @sage444

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i will be captain obviously it`s looking like file encoding error after port. Russian texts sometimes ussing cp-1251 encoding not utf. I hope i will help you to find solution.

P.s Sorry i dont have enought reputation to add comment so i post it like answer.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on the encoding ? where do we change cp-1251 from utf?